# Unsure how kullback-leibler was invoked in derivation.

Tags: probability-distributions, machine-learning, derivation-of-formulae

I am trying to understand how authors of the [DDPM paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11239.pdf) made the leap from equation 21 to equation 22 in appendix A.

Specifically, it is not clear to me how they managed to convert the **first term of the first equation**, into the kullback-leibler divergence **(KLD)** as the **first term in the second equation**, without "using up" the $\mathbb{E}_q$ on the outside of the brackets.

The [definition of the KLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) assumes a term that seems to be missing here.

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_q \left[ -\log \frac{p(X_T)}{q(X_T | X_0)} - \sum_{t>1} \log \frac{p_\theta(X_{t-1}|X_t)}{q(X_{t-1}|X_t, X_0)} - \log p_\theta(X_0|X_1) \right] \tag{21}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
= \mathbb{E}_q \left[ D_{KL}(q(X_T | X_0) || p(X_T)) + \sum_{t>1} D_{KL}(q(X_{t-1}|X_t, X_0) || p_\theta(X_{t-1}|X_t)) - \log p_\theta(X_0|X_1) \right] \tag{22}
\end{equation}